# MVC5 Replacing "UserProfile" AccountModel with LinqToSQL

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, linq-to-sql

I may have been a little ambitious in my attempt to move from WebForms to MVC. To begin with I started with an MVC4 sample project, which I then upgraded the project to MVC5 using [this guide](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) (which went fine).

I then attempted to link my database to the sample application, this is where I may have gone a bit wrong; I've connected to my database using LinqToSql. I expanded a fair bit on the table set generated by the MVC4 sample, the problem I'm now hitting is that the LinqToSql Model generated by pulling in my tables has superseded the existing "UserProfile" model found under "AccountModels.cs" (I retained the "UserProfile" title of the users table & removed the identically named Model).

Everything builds fine, but on attempting to log in or register I'm seeing the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Invalid object name 'UserProfile'.

Which is cropping up in the "AccountController" code:

```
//
// POST: /Account/Login

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login( LoginModel model, string returnUrl ) {
    if ( ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login( model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe ) ) {
        return RedirectToLocal( returnUrl );
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError( "", "The user name or password provided is incorrect." );
    return View( model );
}
```

Is using the LinqToSql Model for UserProfile possible, or have I gone completely the wrong direction with account control here?

Thanks

Comment: I should probably mention, the "sample" I keep referring to if the standard MVC 4 template in VS2013.

Comment: "Invalid object name" implies that there is no `UserProfile` table in the database.  Are you sure the identity models are connecting to the right database?  Are they using a different connection string?  Try using a SQL profiler on the database to see the exact query being executed when this error occurs.

Comment: This turned out to be the schema I set the tables up with, a little fiddling & I got it working.